# How to read and write to and from json file from graphql nestjs server in typescript

Tags: json, typescript, react-redux, graphql, nestjs

I'm currently working with React, Redux, ApolloClient (typescipt) as frontend and i'm using nestjs and graphql at backend. The data sent from frontend gets stored in the in-memory of the graphql and when the server is refreshed the data is lost. Instead of having database, i want to use JSON file to store the data and load the data from json when the server is started to populate the frontend.

I'm bit confused where the connectivity to JSON file will come at server side.
and how will graphql will be connected to the JSON.

It would be really helpful if anyone can guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure why you want to use a file over a database, but the connectivity to the JSON file will come from the server side (obviously) probably through the `fs` package where you have functions like `readFile` and `writeFile` and their synchronous variants as well. You will need some sort of service layer that will be between your GraphQL resolvers and your file read/write service to facilitate the business logic.

You may find it advantageous to create several file readers/writers and to manage each different entity's file as a separate file (then again, maybe not depending on how many entities you have).

GraphQL doesn't really have a connection to JSON files, just like RESTful calls don't have a connection to JSON files, they are protocols and methods of transporting/requesting data over the internet. It will be up to your server to act as an intermediary between the request and the file, and to retrieve/store the expected data and tell the response how to react to the request.

Overall, using a database would be a more robust, and firmer solution, but you could make it work with a file if you absolutely wanted to (as much of an anti-pattern as it may be).

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer, i would like to know what kind of service layer can i use between Graphql resolver and json? Are you talking about gatsby ? or is there anything else i can use.

Comment: By service layer, I'm talking about a service class that you write for your server that will handle the reading and writing so that your business logic doesn't get mixed up with your R/W logic. As I said in the answer, you have the `fs` package built in to read files from the machine your server is hosted on. If you are looking to keep the files elsewhere, like an S3 bucket, then you'll need a method to pull the files from S3, read/write, and send them back to S3. Otherwise, you just need to write a class to handle the R/W logic.

Comment: Thanks for the help Jay. I'll post the update soon.

Comment: Hi Jay it was really simple, as you said just to use fs package, but in my case readFile didn't work instead readFileSync worked and also the writefile worked. :)